# C structs strange behaviour

Tags: c, opencl

I have some long source code that involves a struct definition:

```
struct exec_env {

    cl_program* cpPrograms;
    cl_context cxGPUContext;

    int cpProgramCount;
    int cpKernelCount;
    int nvidia_platform_index;
    int num_cl_mem_buffs_used;
    int total;

    cl_platform_id cpPlatform;
    cl_uint ciDeviceCount;
    cl_int ciErrNum;
    cl_command_queue commandQueue;

    cl_kernel* cpKernels;
    cl_device_id *cdDevices;
    cl_mem* cmMem;
};
```

The strange thing, is that the output of my program is dependent on the order in which I declare the components of this struct. Why might this be?

EDIT:

Some more code:

```
int HandleClient(int sock) {

struct exec_env my_env;

int err, cl_err;
int rec_buff [sizeof(int)];

log("[LOG]: In HandleClient. \n");

my_env.total = 0;

//in anticipation of some cl_mem buffers, we pre-emtively init some. Later, we should have these
//grow/shrink dynamically.
my_env.num_cl_mem_buffs_used = 0;
if ((my_env.cmMem = (cl_mem*)malloc(MAX_CL_BUFFS * sizeof(cl_mem))) == NULL)
    {
        log("[ERROR]:Failed to allocate memory for cl_mem structures\n");
        //let the client know
        replyHeader(sock, MALLOC_FAIL, UNKNOWN, 0, 0);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

my_env.cpPlatform = NULL;
my_env.ciDeviceCount = 0;
my_env.cdDevices = NULL;
my_env.commandQueue = NULL;
my_env.cxGPUContext = NULL;

while(1){

    log("[LOG]: Awaiting next packet header... \n");


    //read the first 4 bytes of the header 1st, which signify the function id. We later switch on this value
    //so we can read the rest of the header which is function dependent.
    if((err = receiveAll(sock,(char*) &rec_buff, sizeof(int))) != EXIT_SUCCESS){
        return err;
    }

    log("[LOG]: Got function id %d \n", rec_buff[0]);
    log("[LOG]: Total Function count: %d \n", my_env.total);
    my_env.total++;

    //now we switch based on the function_id
    switch (rec_buff[0]) {
    case CREATE_BUFFER:;
            {
                //first define a client packet to hold the header
                struct clCreateBuffer_client_packet my_client_packet_hdr;
                int client_hdr_size_bytes = CLI_PKT_HDR_SIZE + CRE_BUFF_CLI_PKT_HDR_EXTRA_SIZE;

                //buffer for the rest of the header (except the size_t)
                int header_rec_buff [(client_hdr_size_bytes - sizeof(my_client_packet_hdr.buff_size))];
                //size_t header_rec_buff_size_t [sizeof(my_client_packet_hdr.buff_size)];
                size_t header_rec_buff_size_t [1];

                //set the first field
                my_client_packet_hdr.std_header.function_id = rec_buff[0];

                //read the rest of the header
                if((err = receiveAll(sock,(char*) &header_rec_buff, (client_hdr_size_bytes - sizeof(my_client_packet_hdr.std_header.function_id) - sizeof(my_client_packet_hdr.buff_size)))) != EXIT_SUCCESS){
                    //signal the client that something went wrong. Note we let the client know it was a socket read error at the server end.
                    err = replyHeader(sock, err, CREATE_BUFFER, 0, 0);
                    cleanUpAllOpenCL(&my_env);
                    return err;
                }

                //read the rest of the header (size_t)
                if((err = receiveAll(sock, (char*)&header_rec_buff_size_t, sizeof(my_client_packet_hdr.buff_size))) != EXIT_SUCCESS){
                    //signal the client that something went wrong. Note we let the client know it was a socket read error at the server end.
                    err = replyHeader(sock, err, CREATE_BUFFER, 0, 0);
                    cleanUpAllOpenCL(&my_env);
                    return err;
                }

                log("[LOG]: Got the rest of the header, packet size is %d \n", header_rec_buff[0]);
                log("[LOG]: Got the rest of the header, flags are %d \n", header_rec_buff[1]);
                log("[LOG]: Buff size is %d \n", header_rec_buff_size_t[0]);

                //set the remaining fields
                my_client_packet_hdr.std_header.packet_size = header_rec_buff[0];
                my_client_packet_hdr.flags = header_rec_buff[1];
                my_client_packet_hdr.buff_size = header_rec_buff_size_t[0];

                //get the payload (if one exists)
                int payload_size = (my_client_packet_hdr.std_header.packet_size - client_hdr_size_bytes);
                log("[LOG]: payload_size is %d \n", payload_size);
                char* payload = NULL;

                if(payload_size != 0){

                    if ((payload = malloc(my_client_packet_hdr.buff_size)) == NULL){
                            log("[ERROR]:Failed to allocate memory for payload!\n");
                            replyHeader(sock, MALLOC_FAIL, UNKNOWN, 0, 0);
                            cleanUpAllOpenCL(&my_env);
                            return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    }

                    if((err = receiveAllSizet(sock, payload, my_client_packet_hdr.buff_size)) != EXIT_SUCCESS){
                        //signal the client that something went wrong. Note we let the client know it was a socket read error at the server end.
                        err = replyHeader(sock, err, CREATE_BUFFER, 0, 0);
                        free(payload);
                        cleanUpAllOpenCL(&my_env);
                        return err;
                    }

                }

                //make the opencl call
                log("[LOG]: ***num_cl_mem_buffs_used before***: %d \n", my_env.num_cl_mem_buffs_used);
                cl_err = h_clCreateBuffer(&my_env, my_client_packet_hdr.flags, my_client_packet_hdr.buff_size, payload, &my_env.cmMem);
                my_env.num_cl_mem_buffs_used = (my_env.num_cl_mem_buffs_used+1);
                log("[LOG]: ***num_cl_mem_buffs_used after***: %d \n", my_env.num_cl_mem_buffs_used);

                 //send back the reply with the error code to the client
                log("[LOG]: Sending back reply header \n");

                if((err = replyHeader(sock, cl_err, CREATE_BUFFER, 0, (my_env.num_cl_mem_buffs_used -1))) != EXIT_SUCCESS){
                   //send the header failed, so we exit
                   log("[ERROR]: Failed to send reply header to client, %d \n", err);
                   log("[LOG]: OpenCL function result was %d \n", cl_err);
                   if(payload != NULL) free(payload);
                   cleanUpAllOpenCL(&my_env);
                   return err;
                }

                //now exit if failed
                if(cl_err != CL_SUCCESS){
                    log("[ERROR]: Error executing OpenCL function clCreateBuffer %d \n", cl_err);
                    if(payload != NULL) free(payload);
                    cleanUpAllOpenCL(&my_env);
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

            }
            break;
```

Now what's really interesting is the call to h_clCreateBuffer. This function is as follows

```
int h_clCreateBuffer(struct exec_env* my_env, int flags, size_t size, void* buff, cl_mem* all_mems){

/*
 * TODO:
 * Sort out the flags.
 * How do we store cl_mem objects persistantly? In the my_env struct? Can we have a pointer int the my_env
 * struct that points to a mallocd area of mem. Each malloc entry is a pointer to a cl_mem object. Then we
 * can update the malloced area, growing it as we have more and more cl_mem objects.
 */

//check that we have enough pointers to cl_mem. TODO, dynamically expand if not
if(my_env->num_cl_mem_buffs_used == MAX_CL_BUFFS){
    return CL_MEM_OUT_OF_RANGE;
}

int ciErrNum;
cl_mem_flags flag;
if(flags == CL_MEM_READ_WRITE_ONLY){
    flag = CL_MEM_READ_WRITE;
}

if(flags == CL_MEM_READ_WRITE_OR_CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR){
    flag = CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR;
}

log("[LOG]: Got flags. Calling clCreateBuffer\n");
log("[LOG]: ***num_cl_mem_buffs_used before in function***: %d \n", my_env->num_cl_mem_buffs_used);
all_mems[my_env->num_cl_mem_buffs_used] = clCreateBuffer(my_env->cxGPUContext, flag , size, buff, &ciErrNum);
log("[LOG]: ***num_cl_mem_buffs_used after in function***: %d \n", my_env->num_cl_mem_buffs_used);

log("[LOG]: Finished clCreateBuffer with id: %d \n", my_env->num_cl_mem_buffs_used);
//log("[LOG]: Finished clCreateBuffer with id: %d \n", buff_counter);
return ciErrNum;
}
```

The first time round the while loop, my_env->num_cl_mem_buffs_used is increased by 1. However, the next time round the loop, after the call to clCreateBuffer, the value of my_env->num_cl_mem_buffs_used gets reset to 0. This does not happen when I change the order in which I declare the members of the struct! Thoughts? Note that I've omitted the other case statements, all of which so similar things, i.e. updating the structs members.

Comment: Sample input/output would be helpful

Comment: Can we see the function that creates the output? And the output itself?

Comment: Hi all. So I realise I'm a bit short on info here so I'll try to expand;

Comment: I'm aware that the compiler adds padding to the struct members. However, what is happening is that I pass a pointer to the struct as a function parameter. The function then in turn calls some Open CL functions, which are passed the struct members via the -> notation. The program output is as expected when the structs components are declared in this order, but not when changed. At no time do I call sizeof. Ill post more code tomorrow when I'm back at work!

Comment: If the struct is redefined, then everything that uses it's definition needs to be recompiled.  Is there a rebuild of all modues that know about the struct?

Comment: Yeah, its only one binary, and none of my own libraries (there's a few sys libs, for example to use sockets). Debian Lenny, Using Netbeans 6.9. I'll check the gcc version tomorrow. The struct is defined in a separate header file, but is part of the project and is hence part of any clean and build operation.

Comment: What is the order of your struct members in which this problem does not arise?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if your program dumps the raw memory content of the object of your struct type, then  the output will obviously depend on the ordering of the fields inside your struct. So, here's one obvious scenario that will create such a dependency. There are many others.

Why are you surprised that the output of your program depends on that order? In general, there's nothing strange in that dependency. If you base your verdict of on the knowledge of the rest of the code, then I understand. But people here have no such knowledge and we are not telepathic.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell. Maybe you can post some code. If I had to guess, I'd say you were casting some input file (made of bytes) into this struct. In that case, you must have the proper order declared (usually standardized by some protocol) for your struct in order to properly cast or else risk invalidating your data.

For example, if you have file that is made of two bytes and you are casting the file to a struct, you need to be sure that your struct has properly defined the order to ensure correct data.

```
struct example1
{
   byte foo;
   byte bar;
};

struct example2
{
   byte bar;
   byte foo;
};

//...

char buffer[];
//fill buffer with some bits

(example1)buffer; 
(example2)buffer;
//those two casted structs will have different data because of the way they are    defined.
```

In this case, "buffer" will always be filled in the same manner, as per some standard.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the output depends on the order. Order of fields in a struct matters.

An additional explanation to the other answers posted here: the compiler may be adding padding between fields in the struct, especially if you are on a 64 bit platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using binary serialization, then your best bet is an invalid pointer issue. Like +1 error, or some invalid pointer arithmetics can cause this. But it is hard to know without code. And it is still hard to know, even with the code. You may try to use some kind of pointer validation/tracking system to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

other guesses

by changing the order you are having different uninitialized values in the struct. A pointer being zero or not zero for example

you somehow manage to overrun an item (by casting ) and blast later items. Different items get blasted depending on order

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if your code uses on "old style" initializer as from C89. For a simple example

```
struct toto {
  unsigned a;
  double b;
};
.
.
toto A = { 0, 1 };
```

If you interchange the fields in the definition this remains a valid initializer, but your fields are initialized completely different. Modern C, AKA C99, has designated initializers for that:

```
toto A = { .a = 0, .b = 1 };
```

Now, even when reordering your fields or inserting a new one, your initialization remains valid.

This is a common error which is perhaps at the origin of the initializerphobia that I observe in many C89 programs.

Answer (score 0):

You have 14 fields in your struct, so there is **14!** possible ways the compiler and/or standard C library can order them during the output.

If you think from the compiler designer's point of view, what should the order be?  Random is certainly not useful.  The only useful order is the order in which the struct fields were declared by you.